# Qt QMainWindow: In included file: field has incomplete type 'QString'

Tags: c++, qt, error-handling, qmake

i have a new project build in Qt version 6.4.1 The only thing i did was adding 2 new classes "ressource" and "process". Process uses ressources.

When i generated them, directly without any doubt i have an error in my mainwindow?!
`#include <QMainWindow>` Error: In included file: filed has incomplete type 'QString'
I didnt change anything.

I use MinGW 64Bit

Thank you, its for a project in University -.-

```
#ifndef RESSOURCE_H
#define RESSOURCE_H

#include <QDebug>

using namespace std;

class Ressource{
private:
    QString name;
    int ressourceId;
    int count;
public:
    int getRessourceId() const;

    void setRessourceId(int ressourceId);

    const QString &getName() const {
        return name;
    }

    void setName(const QString &name) {
        Ressource::name = name;
    }

    int getCount() const {
        return count;
    }

    void setCount(int count) {
        Ressource::count = count;
    }
    Ressource(QString name, int ressourceId, int count);
    void print();
};

#endif // RESSOURCE_H
```

```
#ifndef PROCESS_H
#define PROCESS_H

#include <vector>
#include <ressource.h>

using namespace std;

class Process {
private:
    QString name;
    int processId;
public:

    int getProcessId() const;
    void setProcessId(int processId);

private:
    vector<Ressource> neededRessources;
    vector<Ressource> assignedRessources;
public:
    const QString &getName() const {
        return name;
    }

    void setName(const QString &name) {
        Process::name = name;
    }

    const vector<Ressource> &getNeededRessources() const {
        return neededRessources;
    }

    void setNeededRessources(const vector<Ressource> &neededRessources) {
        Process::neededRessources = neededRessources;
    }

    const vector<Ressource> &getAssignedRessources() const {
        return assignedRessources;
    }

    void setAssignedRessources(const vector<Ressource> &assignedRessources) {
        Process::assignedRessources = assignedRessources;
    }

public:
    Process(QString name,int processId, int min, int max);
    void requestRessource(Ressource ressource, int count);
    void releaseRessource(Ressource ressource, int count);
    void print();
};

#endif // PROCESS_H
```

Its will be a project, which simulates a Deadlock. For that i need Ressources which are used by Processes. The only thing i did was generating the basic structure of those.

Comment: If you use `QString` in your class, you need to `#include <QString>`

Comment: BTW, [why is using namespace std; considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I change the includes, but i still got errors in the mainwindow.h
`#include <QMainWindow>` 
Error: mainwindow.h:4:10: In included file: base class has incomplete type
ressource.h:7:19: error occurred here
qtclasshelpermacros.h:81:7: forward declaration of 'QObject'